# Gremlin union method throws exception using otherV method

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I ran these codes:

1. `g.V().has("name", "Jones").union(g.of().bothE("knows").inV()).values()`
2. `g.V().has("name", "Jones").union(g.of().bothE("knows").otherV()).values()`

The first one returns correctly, but brings Jones too.
The second one throws an exception, that is shown bellow:

`Path tracking is not supported by this Traverser: class com.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversers.SimpleTraverser`

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks,
Celso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh. The short term fix is to `withPath()` after the V(). (assuming TP 3.0.0.M6).

Comment: I'm using TP 3.0.0.M5. I'll try it tomorrow morning (in Brazil) and I'll tell you if that resolved my issue. Thank you Marko

Comment: Marko, I downloaded the gremlin-console-3.0.0.M6 but when I tried to run the .bat it throws: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.RemoteAcceptor`. Could you help me, please? Thanks.

Comment: I included the gremlin-groovy-3.0.0.M6.jar inside lib folder and it solved this issue. Is it any deploy issue or I forgot something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is the intended behavior, but why do you use `union` at all? Why not simply:

```
g.V().has("name", "Jones").bothE("knows").otherV().values()
```

Comment: Oh sorry...I just took off some code, but the main idea is join different kind of relations in just one "query". Thx @daniel-kupptiz